# How to calculate the number of triplets in the rows of matrix in r?

Tags: r, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    3    1    6    8    8    8
[2,]    2    2    5    7    9    7    4
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
```

and I want to calculate the number of triples in each column.

So I expect a vector such as: `[1,0,0,0]` as the result since only the first row contains three adjacent identical matrices.

Is there any function in R to accomplish this, and that doesn't involve writing a long function?

---

OK, I am risking here, but, reflecting the comments, and also because it doesn't make much sense to split the question in two (debatable), let me ask what I am really after: Detecting `4` triplets (or the absence thereof) in each row of a matrix such as:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18]
 [1,]    0    1    2    3    8    4    4    5    6     7     7     7     8     8     8     9     9     9
 [2,]    0    1    2    0    2    3    3    3    4     5     5     5     6     7     7     7     8     9
 [3,]    0    1    1    1    2    7    2    3    4     4     4     5     6     7     7     7     8     9
 [4,]    0    1    1    1    2    3    4    9    4     5     5     5     6     6     6     7     8     9
 [5,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    2    3    4     5     6     6     6     7     8     8     8     9
 [6,]    0    1    2    3    4    5    5    5    6     6     6     7     8     8     8     9     9     9
 [7,]    0    1    2    3    3    3    4    5    5     5     6     6     6     7     8     9     9     9
 [8,]    0    1    2    3    4    5    5    5    6     6     6     7     7     7     8     9     9     9
```

Comment: In the new dataset, I can find lots of triplets, but no quartlets

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry if I'm not expressing myself well, perhaps... I need to detect the presence of four triplets in a row. So for instance, row 8 would be TRUE, because (5,6,7,9) appear three times each side-by-side.

Comment: All of those are not appearing side-by-side  If you look at 7 and 9, there is an 8 value between them.

Comment: right, it would be triplet no. 1 = (5,5,5); triplet no. 2 = (6,6,6); triplet no. 3 = (7,7,7); and triplet no. 4 = (9,9,9).

Comment: Please check my updated answer.  It gives `[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE` as there are four triplets in the last four rows.  For example. in row No. 5, `triplet 1 = (0,0,0), 2 = (1, 1, 1), 3=(6,6,6), and 4 = (8, 8, 8)`

Comment: If your condition is that 4 triplets should be side-by-side, none of the rows would satisfy that one as the last one, have 8 in between (as I already mentioned)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
apply(m, 1, function(x) any(tabulate(rleid(x))==3))
#[1] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

If we need to find whether there are 4 triplets in a row (based on the new dataset)

```
apply(m1, 1, function(x) sum(tabulate(rleid(x))==3))==4
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

#### data

```
library(psych)
m <- `dimnames<-`(as.matrix(read.clipboard()), NULL)
m1 <- `dimnames<-`(as.matrix(read.clipboard()), NULL)
```

NOTE: The datasets were read after copying each of the data output showed in the OP's post and using `read.clipboard` from `psych`.

Comment: Thank you. Things have gotten a bit messy, and I should have edited the question. What I really, really need is to detect the presence or absence of   four triplets in each row.

Comment: @AntoniParellada  There is no four triplets in the example you showed

Comment: Right. I thought I was going to be able to extend it. Should I edit my OP?

Comment: I'm checking... Out of curiosity, how do you import my matrix into R?

Comment: It seems to be working. Before I check my accept to your answer. Is it true that Adam's code wouldn't work, like Gopala is stating?

Comment: @AntoniParellada  Regarding your first question, you can use `library(psych);m1 <- "dimnames<-"(as.matrix(read.clipboard()), NULL)`  after copying the matrix output you showed in the post. For the second, if you are looking for adjacent elements that occur in triplets, the `table` code will not work as it gets the frequency from the whole row.

Comment: Thank you. I think that closes the post very nicely. Thank you for the add'l help!

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use the lag operator from `dplyr` package as follows:

```
apply(m, 1, function(x) any((x == lag(x)) & (x == lag(x, 2))))
```

A more general sequence of numbers perhaps can be calculated as follows:

```
apply(m, 1, function(x) all(diff(which(diff(x) == 0)) == 1) & (length(which(diff(x) == 0)) == 2))
```

Where that last 2 is the (n - 1) where n = 3 in this case. You can also optimize it some by not computing that `which(diff(x....)` part twice.

Output for your example is:

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Seems like there is this function in base called `rle` that computes run lengths of each value in a vector. You can use it as follows:

```
apply(m, 1, function(x) any(rle(x)$lengths == 3))
```

Giving you the same output:

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Can you think of a way of detecting 4 triplets in a row?

Comment: Updated my answer with another option...bit long, but you can crispen it up some.

Comment: Can you detect 4 triplets in each row?

Comment: Yes, change that 3 at the end of that `rle` based one to 4...if you want 10, change it to 10..works for any number.